# Is there any option to set the custom replication factor in Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I want to use a custom replication factor in all my topics while creation. Im running 7 node cluster and I want to set 5 as the replication factor for all of my topics.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect connectors cannot create their own topics with custom settings. This is something that's slated for improvement with [KIP-158](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-158:+Kafka+Connect+should+allow+source+connectors+to+set+topic-specific+settings+for+new+topics).

As things currently (Apache Kafka 2.4) stand, connectors can only rely on the broker creating them automatically (if `auto.create.topics.enable=true`) with the default replication factor etc, or you can [pre-create them](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#adding-topics) and at that point set the required replication factor.